# STL map gets corrupted with mpz_class (GMP) values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, gmp

I have an `std::map<mpz_class,int>` (for those unfamiliar, `mpz_class` is a class container for a very large integer number, defined by GMP, Gnu Multiprecision Library). I use a custom Comparator which uses GMP's `cmp()` function. In the map, I have inserted several `std::pair<mpz_class,int>` with correct values (they are reasonable when I print them).

However, I noticed `map::find` was not working correctly, so I printed what the Comparator is comparing. It turns out the second element (key) is always a very wild value integer value, like 128957236027369832796823768439267, way out of scale of the integers I'm working with.

Is there some sort of memory corruption going on that I'm unawares of? Perhaps `mpz_class` cannot be used in this fashion? How would I work around this problem? I haven't had this problem with other containers so far.

```
#include <map>
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Equaler {
    inline bool operator()(const mpz_class a, const mpz_class b) const {
        std::cout << " about to return " << a << "," << b << "," << cmp(a,b) << "\n";
        return cmp(a, b);
    }
};

int main() {
    mpz_class x("38268");
    std::map<mpz_class,int,Equaler> map;
    map.insert(std::pair<mpz_class,int>(x,42));
    map.find(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
about to return 38268,812462232382732367817613904064203084469901797507,-2
```

Comment: Show your code. A complete, compileable example that demonstrates the problem, along with your expected vs. actual results.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::map<mpz_class, int>`?

Comment: Side comment: the line `map.insert(std::pair<mpz_class,int>(x,42));` may not be wrong but it is silly: look at map::value_type, and if you don't mind copying, there is `make_pair`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your comparator.  `std::map` expects a comparator which returns true if the first operand should be considered less than the second, and false otherwise.  But `cmp` works differently.  It doesn't return a boolean, it returns an integer, in one of three possible states:

- negative : lhs < rhs
- 0 : lhs == rhs
- positive : lhs > rhs

However, a negative and a positive integer, in a boolean context, both evaluate to true, so the results of `cmp` do not convert correctly to what `std::map` expects.  Change this:

```
return cmp(a, b);
```

to this:

```
return cmp(a, b) < 0;
```

Comment: That was probably an additional problem, but the problem remains, I'm afraid. Funny, because when I run the test program, it works as expected.

Comment: Actually, I was too quick to speak. It actually works now - it's strange though, because the second element still prints to "812462232382732367817613904064203084469901797507" and such absurd values. Perhaps internally map does something funny, like compare with invalid locations?

Still, a bit disconcerting, I wish I knew why the numbers appeared absurd like that.

Comment: @bombax: What implementation are you using? I get more comprehensible results here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f152ef878f1f8f

Comment: I am using gcc on ubuntu.

Comment: `mpz_class`s have overloads for `operator<`, so presumably you could drop `cmp` and just `return a < b;` Which means, assuming you only use the print for debugging, you don't really need a comparator at all, your keys are already comparable.